# Can Git bash be setup to not require me to type "git" for every command?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I'm running git bash in Windows and it's a tad annoying to have to put in "git" for every command. I only run git commands in this bash window. Is there any way to get around this?

EDIT: Ok, this is a pretty bad question because bash can be used for so many things, and I do use it for basic commands. What about a way to allow me to type "g" instead of "git"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a cmd session:

```
doskey g=git $*
```

In a bash session

```
alias g=git
```

Beyons a somple alias, you have dedicated shells that avoids typing git completely, like [`thoughtbot/gitsh`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/gitsh) (but it is only for Mac or Linux).
Maybe [`caglar/gitsh`](https://github.com/caglar/gitsh) (perl) is more portable.

Comment: Thanks for the alias idea. Actual syntax is alias g='git' though

Comment: @yts Fixed. I have edited the answer to suggests other shells.

Comment: ah, interesting. I'll probably just stick to git bash to encourage me to work on my bash skills :)